# ¿Se debe usar la etiqueta "lenguaje-no-importa"? actualmente existe la etiqueta "lenguaje-agnostico"

Tags: discusión, solicitud-de-quemado, etiquetas

Considero que la etiqueta "`lenguaje-no-importa`" podría ser eliminada, ya que actualmente tenemos la etiqueta: "`lenguaje-agnostico`", la cual se define como:

> Utilice esta etiqueta para PREGUNTAS DE PROGRAMACIÓN que son
>   independientes de cualquier lenguaje de programación en particular.

Comment: Si deseas, usa el tag [tag:burninate-request] para estas discusiones. Así le vamos dando forma al sitio mientras decidimos su nombre en español :)

Comment: claro que si @JhonAlx , listo!.

Answer (score 6):

Estoy de acuerdo con eliminar [lenguaje-no-importa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-no-importa) pero la otra opción [lenguaje-agnostico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-agnostico) suena un poco extraño en español, tal vez solamente a mi me parece así.

Propongo la etiqueta [independiente-del-lenguaje](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/independiente-del-lenguaje) aunque no es tan concisa, el significado es muy claro.  Si la comunidad está de acuerdo también se eliminaría [lenguaje-agnostico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-agnostico).

Comment: creo que no hay que eliminarlas, hay que ponerlas como sinónimos. Asi evitamos que nuevos usuarios futuros las vuelvan a crear y el doble trabajo de volver a eliminarlas.

Comment: ¡Cierto! había olvidado que existen los sinónimos para etiquetas

Comment: independiente-del-lenguaje no es posible porque tiene 26 caracteres y solo se admiten 25. independiente-de-lenguaje sí sería posible y creo que es lo que mejor expresa el concepto. Lo de los sinónimos es la mejor opción.

Comment: Entonces, ¿no hay ninguna objeción a [tag:independiente-de-lenguaje] ?